# GCloud: Creating instance template with docker container and GPU

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, gpu, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Using gcloud, I want to create an instance template of type `n1-standard-1` with an attached GPU and a docker container. This can be done through the console but I want to do it from the command line.

It is possible to create an instance template with GPU using `gcloud alpha compute instance-templates create` and the `--accelerator` option.

It is also possible to create an instance template with a container using `gcloud alpha compute instance-templates create-with-container` but in this case the `--accelerator` option is not recognized.

... but it is not possible to both specify the container image **and** request GPU or am I missing something ? Any work-around beside creating the template manualy using the console ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to create an *instance* with accelerators and a container with `gcloud` by creating the instance with accelerators and then using `gcloud beta compute instances update-container` to set the container, but it is not currently possible to create an instance template with accelerators and a container with `gcloud`.

You can file a feature request for that functionality at:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=0